# Syntax highlight the opening parenthesis line printed in echo area

Tags: balanced-parentheses

With respect to this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3468/174), is there any way to enable syntax highlighting for the text printed in echo area by `blink-matching-open`? I am asking for something similar to what [Lua Block mode](https://github.com/tr37ion/lua-block-mode) does.

[image: Lua_Block]

For reference, this is the current behaviour:

[image]

Comment: The very last line of `blink-matching-open` calls `substring-no-properties` on the text that is being printed. If you remove the call to that function then it'll work as you wish

Comment: @Jules: Please consider posting that as an answer (maybe showing the code).

Comment: @Jules Is there a better way of doing this than copying the function definition of `blink-matching-open` over to my init.el and modify it to redefine it? Since then it would put the onus on me to check if the function ever gets updated upstream.

Comment: @NamanDixit: I don't see any other way to add this behavior. I don't think advices wouldn't work in this case. The only other idea that I have would be to add a `defcustom` to the emacs master branch to toggle the behavior that you want, which may be more work than you were hoping for. For what its worth it doesn't seem like this function has changed significantly in a while...

Comment: @Drew: I didn't feel like having my comment be an answer because I didn't feel like spending too much time writing it up and I didn't think that it really solved the problem cleanly